# Iterate over JSON object and check if parsed query matches

Tags: javascript, json, object, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt JS 2.4.5 and I'm trying to itterate over a JSON object that's been imported to see if it contains a match based on providing a query in the URL, e.g: `mysite.com/page?id=TEST` - where if `TEST` isn't found in my imported JSON object then do something.

I've current got a foreach loop set up to iterate over my JSON object which is imported correctly, it doesn't seem to manage to run my code if it can't find what's parsed.

To add context, here's the bits of code:

**JSON**

```
{
  "id_1": "something here",
  "id_2": "something else here"
}
```

**JS**

```
var iframe_settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iframe_settings'));
this.iframe_settings = iframe_settings

for (var aff in this.affiliates) {
        if (this.affiliates.hasOwnProperty(aff)) {
          if (aff != this.iframe_settings.id) {
            // do something if ?id=X isn't found in JSON object
          }
        }
      }
```

From the above foreach loop and provided JSON, I'm trying to loop over my JSON object and check whether `mysite.com/page?id=id_3` can be found within the JSON object, if it can't then run the code where I've got the `// do something`

Passing `?id=id_3` is stored in Localstorage via: `localStorage.setItem('iframe_settings', JSON.stringify(this.$route.query));` but this isn't the problem, the problem is my foreach loop.

If `mysite.com/page?id=id_3` can be found, e.g: `id_2` then it shouldn't run the if statement.

**EDIT**

`this.affiliates` is located inside of `data ()`

```
import AffiliatesFromJson from '~/static/affiliates/affiliates.json';

export default {
  data () {
    affiliates: AffiliatesFromJson
  }
}
```

Comment: what is this.affiliates?

Comment: There's not  much idea to iterate over [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ..?

Comment: `this.affiliates` is importing the actual JSON object from a file, I've updated the code snippets above, see **edit**

Comment: Since it's an object, just `if ( !this.affiliates.hasOwnProperty( theID ))` should suffice as a check to know that theID does not exists in this.affiliates. If you would use an array instead of an object, same can be done with .find( data => data.id === theID ) . ( Good example of why I prefer arrays with fixed properties over an object where the property key is the id. )

Comment: Thanks @Shilly, this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

this is file name affiliates

```
{
   "id": "something here",
   "id": "something else here"
}
```

import from json file:

```
import Affiliates from './affiliates.json'

Affiliates.map((p)=> {
   console.log(p.id)
}
```